# How to uninstall Ubuntu One?

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-one

I've looked in the Software Center, and there is an entry under Accessories for Ubuntu One, but I'm not sure if that'll actually remove Ubuntu One. On Ubuntu One's website, it gives a bunch of terminal commands to remove it, so should I use those or use the entry in the Software Center?

The reason I'm trying to remove Ubuntu One is because its sync doesn't work with my comp for some reason. It keeps saying that its trying to sync files in the client window, then it stops with the red X next to it after a few seconds. If Ubuntu One is this useless, I see no use for having it on my computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed it through the Software Center and haven't had any problems since. I'm not sure if its completely removed, but it doesn't show up anywhere I see on my computer (not even the messaging menu). The Ubuntu One folder in my Documents was still there though so I had to remove that.

Comment: I found it does not remove it completely. I followed @joelalmeidaptg instructions below to completely remove it.

Answer (score 11):

Ubuntu One is spread over many packages. You can remove them by running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone* python-ubuntuone-storage*
```

Comment: ubuntu one is good, but not able to configure, so I also decide to do in this way, thank you for sharing.

Comment: The right command to use is $ sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone* python-ubuntuone* gir1.2-ubuntuoneui* rhythmbox-ubuntuone because with your command you would miss 2 other python-ubuntuone packages : python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel then another 2 packages gir1.2 and rythmbox plugin.

Answer (score 4):

To completely remove Ubuntu One, just close U1 services and type this on your console (ctrl + alt + t)

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.share/local/ubuntuone
rm -rf ~/.cache/ubuntuone
rm -rf ~/.config/ubuntuone
mv ~/Ubuntu\ One/ ~/Ubuntu\ One_old/
Open Applications->Accessories->Passwords and Encryption Keys, go to the Passwords tab, delete the Ubuntu One token
sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone*
```

This will remove Ubuntu One and all of its settings, and move your files to a folder called Ubuntu One_old in your home directory!

Comment: I like how you delete the user's shares without warning, there. Also that you remove the applications data and cache directories without stopping and removing the application first. And when I say "like" I mean "think it shows a potentially data-loss level of stupidity". Please do not do this. Please do not suggest that people do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say to close all U1 services... I was just trying to help. This code will remove the application completely, witch was what then user wanted to do.

Comment: This is, in fact, what is suggested on the Ubuntu One website

Answer (score 0):

Firstly run `sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone-installer*`

then run `sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone*`